# Trying to only print specific numbers in this Array Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

For some reason I have only managed as far as printing the odd numbers, but it somehow still prints what appears to be values that are null. I am trying to only print the values that returned as odd.

```
public class Odd {

    public int[] removeEvens(int [] nums) {  //start of method
           
        int [] newArray = new int[nums.length];
        
        int count = 0;
        
        // start of array conversion
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                    
            newArray[count] = nums[i];
            count++;
            
            }
        
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
            if (newArray[i] % 2 == 1)
                newArray[counter++] = newArray[i];
        for (int i=counter; i < nums.length; i++)
            newArray[i] = 0;  
        
          
                    
    return newArray;    
    }
        // end of method 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Odd labObject = new Odd();
          int [] input = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
          int [] result = labObject.removeEvens(input);
          
          // Helper method Arrays.toString() converts int[] to a String
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // Should print [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved by working out the correct size of the new array first before you create it. Then simply loop the array and only store the odd numbers. Otherwise, remove/trim the array size before returning it.

Here is a solution by modifying your `removeEvens` method:

```
public int[] removeEvens(int[] nums)
{  //start of method

    int count = 0;

    // start of array conversion
    // Count the odd numbers to work out the array length
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] % 2 == 1 || nums[i] % 2 == -1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Now create a new array of the correct length
    int[] newArray = new int[count];

    // Now loop through the original array and only store the odd numbers in the new array
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] % 2 == 1 || nums[i] % 2 == -1)
        {
            newArray[counter] = nums[i];
            counter ++;
        }
    }

    // Return the result
    return newArray;
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: The exercise needs to be done without modifying the method. In other words, I need to focus in modifying the method itself.

Comment: @Jake I don't understand, do you, or do you not need to modify the method? Half of the code in your current `removeEvens` method is pointless.

Comment: So sori, this is an exercise as I am a student. I am sure it is pointless so I will explain to you a bit better and hopefully you can provide me the feedback.

The test program is going to  test nums with different ranges. But it needs to only return odd numbers from those ranges. 

So where nums is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  is tested first

then a range like  [1, 9, 3]   

or [1, 4, 6, 7, 9] etc, and the method needs to not only resize the range but also return the odd numbers etc.

Comment: @Jake The code in my answer does exactly what you want. It will return an array of the correct length with only the odd numbers, and it will work for any array that you pass into the method. I only showed the `removeEvens` part of the code because the rest does not change.

Comment: I forgot to mention sorifiend, it did resolve the issue but it needs to be modified to also return negative numbers too. Can you modify the code for me please!

Comment: @Jake ahh simple, just allow for 1 or -1 on this line `if (nums[i] % 2 == 1 || nums[i] % 2 == -1)`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

change it to `return Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 0, counter);` when you make in array of ints in java with a specified size, it sets every value in the array to 0. Doing this will remove all of the extraneous 0s at the end.

Comment: it could also be `return Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 0, counter-1);`. Try both, one will work